# Centering div logo with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working with the mobile version of this website and I'm stuck with a very simple task: centering the logo in the header. I'm trying to use `flex` and then `justify-content:center;`. This is the "code":

```
<header>
        <div class="container center-me">
            <div class="responsive-logo"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo-holder"></div>
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dot">.</li>
                            <li><a href="{{ Anthony.go_to_product_page }}" class="r_spacer">Anthony</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ Jackson.go_to_product_page }}">Jackson</a></li>
                            <li class="dot">.</li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero"></div>
 </header>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.pullcontainer a#pull { display: none; }
nav ul li a { color: #282f35; -webkit-transition: all .25s ease; -moz-transition: all .25s ease; -ms-transition: all .25s ease; -o-transition: all .25s ease; transition: all .25s ease; }
nav ul li a:hover { color: #838383; text-decoration: none; }
p { text-align: center; font-size: 14px; color: #848789; font-weight: 300; word-spacing: 2px; line-height: 1.8em; margin-top: 25px; }
p.text-intro { font-size: 18px; }
nav { height: 75px; margin-top: 30px; position: relative; }
.logo-holder { background: url(../img/main-logo.png) no-repeat center center; width: 114px; height: 105px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 310px; }
.responsive-logo { display: hidden; }
header { background-color: #f4f5fc; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;}
header ul { padding-top: 35px; }
header ul li { list-style: none; float: left; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; }
header ul li a { display: block; margin: 0 30px; color: #4d4959; }
.r_spacer { margin-right: 150px; }

.active{
    width: 500px;
}
.image-item{
    display: inline;
}
.image-item img{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
}
.image-item img:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
li{
    margin: 0 1.75rem 0 0;
}

.d-flex .col-sm{
    display: block;
}
.form-group label{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
header{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height: 10em;
}
.row .prev-price{
    margin-left: .5em;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.row .actual-price{
    margin-top: 0;
}
.d-flex .container-fluid p{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.container h1{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #353738; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 30px; 
    font-weight: 600;
}
.container .prev-price{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.container .actual-price{
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.buy-btn {
    margin-top: 220px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    border: solid 1px #bbb;
    padding: 15px 50px; 
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 400; 
}
.buy-btn:hover, .buy-btn:focus {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 1s;
    background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    *{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .responsive-logo { background: url(../img/responsive-logo.png) no-repeat center center; width: 110px; height: 44px; position: absolute; left: 10px; align-self: center; justify-self: center; }

    .center-me{
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .pullcontainer{
        display: none;
    }
    #div_id_quantity{
        display: flex;
    }
    #div_id_quantity > label{
        margin-top: .5rem;
        margin-right: .5rem;
    }
    .col-sm::before{
        content: 'Jackson';
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin:30px 10px
    }
    header{
        height:100%;
    }
    .responsive-logo{
        width: 30px;
    }
    .d-flex{
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .container{
        display: flex;
        padding:0!important;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .image-list{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .col-sm{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .col{
        padding: 0!important;
        min-height: 120px;
    }
    .row{
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: .5rem!important;
    }
    .button-wrapper{
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        align-items: baseline;
        justify-items: center;
        padding: 1.5rem;
        z-index: 99;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-color: #f4f5fc;
    }
    .buy-btn{
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 0!important;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    .image-item img{
        width: 75px;
    }
    .active{
        width: 375px;
    }
    .container-fluid{
        margin-top: .7rem;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .container-fluid h1{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The header has me really confused: Without a height specified, it'll set to 0 and if I eliminate the row inside, it will also set to 0. And on top of that, back to the main issue, the div that has the logo won't center itself...
Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough or some code is lacking. I'm new to this stuff. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase `position: absolute; left: 10px;` from `.responsive-logo`! The flex settings of the parent will be sufficient for centering the logo container.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid much codes.Try adding this instead :

```
.logo-holder{ align-items: center;justify-content:center;display:flex;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` to your `<nav>` element

**See this** [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoxtcnj5/)

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
 *zoom: 1;
}

.pullcontainer a#pull {
 display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
 color: #282f35;
 -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
 -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
 -o-transition: all .25s ease;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #838383;
 text-decoration: none;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #848789;
 font-weight: 300;
 word-spacing: 2px;
 line-height: 1.8em;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

p.text-intro {
 font-size: 18px;
}

nav {
 height: 75px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.logo-holder {
 background: url(../img/main-logo.png) no-repeat center center;
 width: 114px;
 height: 105px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-90px);
}

.logo-holder>img {
 width: 100%;
}

.responsive-logo {
 display: hidden;
}

header {
 background-color: #f4f5fc;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header ul {
 padding-top: 35px;
}

header ul li {
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul li a {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 30px;
 color: #4d4959;
}

.r_spacer {
 margin-right: 150px;
}

.active {
 width: 500px;
}

.image-item {
 display: inline;
}

.image-item img {
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100px;
}

.image-item img:hover {
 border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 margin: 0 1.75rem 0 0;
}

.d-flex .col-sm {
 display: block;
}

.form-group label {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 1.5px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10em;
}

.row .prev-price {
 margin-left: .5em;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

.row .actual-price {
 margin-top: 0;
}

.d-flex .container-fluid p {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.container h1 {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #353738;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.container .prev-price {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 90%;
}

.container .actual-price {
 letter-spacing: 7px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.buy-btn {
 margin-top: 220px;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 background-color: black;
 border: solid 1px #bbb;
 padding: 15px 50px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.buy-btn:hover,
.buy-btn:focus {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
 background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);
}

@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
 * {
  max-width: 100%;
 }
 .responsive-logo {
  background: url(../img/responsive-logo.png) no-repeat center center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
 }
 .center-me {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 .pullcontainer {
  display: none;
 }
 #div_id_quantity {
  display: flex;
 }
 #div_id_quantity>label {
  margin-top: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
 }
 .col-sm::before {
  content: 'Jackson';
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 30px 10px
 }
 header {
  height: 100%;
 }
 .responsive-logo {
  width: 30px;
 }
 .d-flex {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0!important;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
 }
 .image-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
 }
 .col-sm {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .col {
  padding: 0!important;
  min-height: 120px;
 }
 .row {
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: .5rem!important;
 }
 .button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 99;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f5fc;
 }
 .buy-btn {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0!important;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
 }
 .image-item img {
  width: 75px;
 }
 .active {
  width: 375px;
 }
 .container-fluid {
  margin-top: .7rem;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 .container-fluid h1 {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="container center-me">
            <div class="responsive-logo"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <nav>
                        <div class="logo-holder">
                          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x50" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <ul class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dot">.</li>
                            <li><a href="{{ Anthony.go_to_product_page }}" class="r_spacer">Anthony</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ Jackson.go_to_product_page }}">Jackson</a></li>
                            <li class="dot">.</li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero"></div>
 </header>
```